# Why is dataframe is not displaying according to the given condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1. I wanted to create/display the dataframe according to the condition. What am I missing here?
   2.I want to also create the dataframe according to an integer value which would also take the float value into consideration. For e.g.:- train[train['target']==49] then it should also display 49.10 float value present in the dataframe[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsDTX.png)

Comment: Please post your code as *text*, not image. And kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (here `machine-learning` - removed).

Answer (score 0):

Is probably because float value can have large number of decimals, you can set limit by rounding them:

```
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.random(5)
b = np.random.random(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a = a, b = b))


df.head(2)

#   a           b
# 0 0.548814    0.645894
# 1 0.715189    0.437587

(df.a == 0.548814).head(2) # There is no match here
# 0 False
# 1 False

(df.a.round(6) == 0.548814).head(2) #There is match here by rounding
# 0 True
# 1 False
```

If you need only the integer part, the use `astype` method from series, in the example above:

```
df.a = df.a + 1
df.a.head(3)

# 0 1.548814
# 1 1.715189
# 2 1.602763

df[df.a.astype(int) == 1] # this will return a view of all dataframe
```